# Python sketch not working as intended (reading data from CSV)

Tags: python, function, exception, csv

I am currently trying to write a program which runs through a CSV file of academic papers. The CSV is tab deliminated and is in four columns (Author, Date, Title, Journal)

The idea is to ask the user whether he wants to search the group of papers via Author, Paper Title or Journal Title (or press Q to quit), and display the results of the query back to the user in this order: **Author/s. Year. Title. Journal.**

My code runs, but it only retrieves data from the 'search option' I selected. I.E, if I choose to search by Author, it will pull back and display the Authors whose names match the query, but it doesn't display any of the other information (The year, title or journal). This is the same with the other search options (i.e if I select Journal, it will pull back any relevant journals but will not give me the Author, Date or Title of said journal)

Any help here is greatly appreciated! Below is my code.

```
import csv


def AuthorSearch():
    authorSearch = input("Please type Author name. \n")
    for item in Author:
        if item.find(authorSearch) != -1:
            print (item)

def TitleSearch():
    titleSearch = input("Please type in Title, \n")
    for item in Title:
        if item.find(titleSearch) != -1:
            print (item)

def JournalSearch():
    journalSearch = input("Please type in a Journal, \n")
    for item in Journal:
        if item.find(journalSearch) != -1:
            print (item)






data = csv.reader (open('List.txt', 'rt'), delimiter='\t')


Author, Year, Title, Journal = [], [], [], []

for row in data:
    Author.append(row[0])
    Year.append(row[1])
    Title.append(row[2])
    Journal.append(row[3])


print ("Please type in capitals.")
searchOption = input("Press A to search for Author, T to search titles or J to search Journals or press Q to quit. \n" )

if searchOption == 'A':
 AuthorSearch()

elif searchOption == 'T':
    TitleSearch()

elif searchOption == 'J':
    JournalSearch()

elif searchOption == 'Q':
    exit()
```

Thank you very much to anybody who helps, it's really appreciated!

I have googled and read the CSV reference page, but I can't seem to get my head around it. Aagin, all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you put all your info into separate arrays...but you did that because you know their column numbers...so just keep it as is and call by the number!

```
everything = []
for row in data:
    everything.append[row]
```

Here is an example for your title search function:

```
def TitleSearch():
    titleSearch = input("Please type in Title, \n")
    for row in everything:
        title = row[2]
        if title.find(titleSearch) != -1:
            print row
```

so now you take the entire row, and just run your `find()` on the 3rd column (the one you said was title) and if it's the same as your `titleSearch` it will print the entire row with all of the information, problem solved!

Comment: Thank you very very much! That worked wonderfully. If I could give rep I would, but alas I'm a new user so instead all I can give you are my many thanks.

Comment: well you can upvote and mark my answer as correct haha. But of course, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The list `Author` doesn't contain anything but the authors.  When you do `for item in Author`, you are only looking through the authors.  When you then print the found item, it is of course only the author.  You have the same problem with each field.  You have four separate lists of fields that are not linked in any way.

I would suggest you take a look at the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which has nice facilities for reading CSV files into a tabular data structure.  It also does a lot more than that, but it should easily handle what you want to do here.

Comment: Pandas is awesome but potentially overkill for this (though it would be good). You want to make a list of lists, and then search the relevant index in the sublist.

Comment: I believe that this requires an install though? This program is an assignment which will be ran on a different computer, so sadly I don't think this is an option.

Thanks for your help though, I've checked Pandas out, it does look helpful. Sadly just not in this situation.

Comment: And thanks very much Katie - that would make sense. I'll give it a blast!